# How to prevent "yt-dlp" file from being overwritten while playing VRChat?

Tags: virtual-reality, overwrite, yt-dlp

Windows 7 64bit on desktop (no headset) and with VIVE Pro 1 (headset)

**Context**
Everytime I enter a world in the game `VRChat`, videoplayers cause the "A youtube-dl fork with additional features and patches has stopped working" error. I've tried multiple solutions, and only one has kinda worked. Not even VRChat's technical support knew what was wrong.

*Solutions attempted for videoplayer error:*

- https://www.reddit.com/r/VRchat/comments/p3dwi6/vrchat_video_player_doesnt_work_fix/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/VRchat/comments/bnvsp2/help_video_players_not_working_in_vrchat/
- https://help.vrchat.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500002378742-Video-players-aren-t-working
  (I have Windows Media Player, so I [didn't](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/media-feature-pack-for-win7-non-n/9b5e627a-a43a-468d-a920-4d265f19fbb9)
  need to download Windows Media Feature pack)

I haven't tried renewing my IP address since technical support didn't give me the "You're receiving a 'too many requests' error" response like that did for [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/438100/discussions/5/2919976282208387554/#c2949250308636091568) person.

**The Problem**

> I also a had problem on my windows 7 system. I eventually found out,
> that video players now use a newer external programm called
> yt-dlp.exe. (as opposed to the older youtube-dl I was familiar with)
> So for me the fix was to download a version that works with win7 from
> githup and place it into the folder that holds external assets on the
> current game version:
> C:\Users*UserName*\AppData\LocalLow\VRChat\VRChat\Tools
>
> Maybe this can help someone else aswell.
>
> EDIT: **I haven't found out yet how to stop VRchat from automatically
> updating the file, so for the time being I need to replace it with the
> win7 version every time I enter a room with video player.**
> -[Lord Daro](https://steamcommunity.com/app/438100/discussions/0/2959418921947809287/#c3274689286960725269)

This works for the most part, but different worlds (or videoplayers really) work to different degrees (see bottom of [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/438100/discussions/0/3416558908190405254/) post for details), and I'm okay with that for now. Just in case it matters, I think the overwriting occurs while the world is (down)loading.

*Solutions attempted to prevent overwriting:*

- Setting `yt-dlp` to Read-only
- Removing certain permissions (delete,
  create files / write data) from `SYSTEM`, [this user account], and
  `Administrators`